# Adding extra attributes to webform input element

Tags: javascript, webforms

I am looking to run javascript for a textbox on a webform. I am looking to add an extra attribute to my webform, but I am not sure how the webform is rendered . I was able to do that for my cck form using hook form alter but unable to do that for a webform.

Simply I have

```
<input type="text" maxlength="128" name="submitted[school_name_cancer]" id="edit-submitted-school-name-cancer" size="32" value="" class="form-text required" />
```

But I would like

```
<input type="text" maxlength="128" name="submitted[school_name_cancer]" id="edit-submitted-school-name-cancer" onkeyup="lookup(this.value);'" size="32" value="" class="form-text required" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this Form API Quickstart Guide http://drupal.org/node/751826 to review how to build forms, know how a form is builded:

> The Drupal Form API provides sophisticated form techniques and also
>   allows for almost unlimited possibilities for custom theming,
>   validation, and execution of forms. Even better, ANY form (even those
>   in core) can be altered in almost any way imaginable--elements can be
>   removed, added, and rearranged.

if your javascript is for validate fields of your form, I guess that this answer (related with validations of fields) could be useful [How do I create custom content types in drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12416/how-do-i-create-custom-content-types-in-drupal/12419#12419)

Comment: Hi,I was able to do this with a form but I am unable to add custom attribute to a webform element Its hard to know its how it is being referred or the form is being drawn.

Comment: do you refer a form builded using WebForm module http://drupal.org/project/webform ?

Comment: regarding webforms you can review this post about how alter forms of webform module: http://drupal.org/node/454066

Answer (score 0):

I post a solution to that issue at drupal.org, here is the link:

https://www.drupal.org/node/1462436#comment-8974109

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.